# MS Access Second Autonumber Field Option or Workaround

Tags: ms-access, autonumber

I would like to add an AutoNumber field in an Access table but ID is already type Autonumber and is used for the index in the table. You can't have more than one Autonumber field in a table apparently.

The use case is: Existing database of Clients with existing Client_Number record. I want the ability to enter an 'old' client from this database and set their Client_Number to what it is in the existing database (eg Access Autonumbers it as 405 but I'll overtype that with 3245). But I also want to add NEW clients and have the system assign a number automatically (beginning at 4001) if possible.

Can anyone help me or is it impossible? I have googled for a solution but nothing is forthcoming.

Comment: You can always manually insert a value for the AI column.

Comment: Just quickly would some VBA or even a macro work using max()+1 on my Client_Number field?

Comment: @krishKM I tried editing the ID field in my table but it won't allow it - is that because A. it's the table primary key? and/or B. it has a relationship set to another table?

Comment: I don't think it'll allow you via design. You need to either make a append query or plain sql like insert into table (clientid) values (333);

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to remove the auto-increment index from the original column and add it to a new one column (it might require to temporarily remove table/field dependencies, especially when they are cascaded updates/deletes), then you can key in the new values without any risk to loose the index. once the new index has been built up, [reset](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/812718/how-to-reset-an-autonumber-field-value-in-access) it's auto-increment value to 4000 - and the next new record will get 4001. as long as one keeps the old index, one still can use it to update dependent tables with the new IDs - and then add the dependencies towards the recently introduced column - and remove the old index column.